# [Vue warn]: Property or method "list" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive [...]

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, vue.js

I'm browsing characters of the Rick & Morty series app, using vue.js and I'm new to vue.js.

but I'm getting below mentioned error, please help me solve this

Error1 : [Vue warn]: Property or method "list" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

```js
// App.vue file //

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Nav />
    <CharactersList />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Nav from './components/Nav.vue'
import CharactersList from './components/CharactersList'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Nav,
    CharactersList
  }
}
</script>

// CharactersList.vue file //

<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Rick and Morty characters</h1>
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>Character ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Species</td>
                <td>Add to fav</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item.id">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}}}</td>
                <td>{{item.species}}</td>
                <button>Add to fav</button>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
export default {
  name: 'CharactersList',
  data: function () {
    return {
      list: undefined
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    Vue.axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/')
      .then((resp) => {
        debugger
        this.list = resp.data.results
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: What about if you change `list: undefined` to `list: []`?

Comment: @weronika is it solved?

Comment: Thanks, yaaas – it finally works correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to import there Vue and VueAxios, as they are no use there. And second, you need to modify your **list** variable value from **undefined** to **[]**

I have changed your **CharactersList** component code, you can copy and paste all codes, and it will work as the way you want:

**`CharactersList.vue`**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Rick and Morty characters</h1>
        <table border="1px">
            <tr>
                <td>Character ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Species</td>
                <td>Add to fav</td>
            </tr>
            <tr v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item.id">
                <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.species}}</td>
                <button>Add to fav</button>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'CharactersList',
  data: function () {
    return {
      list: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/')
      .then((resp) => {
        this.list = resp.data.results
      })
  }
}
</script>
```